# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified:

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import os

def rename(directory):
    for name in os.listdir(directory):
        print(name)
        os.rename(name,"0"+name)

        
path = input("Enter the file path")
rename(path)
```

I want to rename every file in a certain directory so that it adds a 0 to the beginning of the file name, however when I try to run the code it comes up with this error:

> (FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: '0.jpg' -> '00.jpg')

I'm sure that there is a file in there named `0.jpg` and I'm not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As written you're looking for a file named `0.jpg` in the working directory. You want to be looking in the directory you pass in.

So instead do:

```py
os.rename(os.path.join(directory,name), 
    os.path.join(directory,'0'+name))
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use an absolute path, unless your terminal is in that directory.

Hence, you can do as in the following:

```
import os
def rename(directory):
    os.chdir(directory) # Changing to the directory you specified.
    for name in os.listdir(directory):
        print(name)
        os.rename(name,"0"+name)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am agreeing with [mechanical_meat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35443278/filenotfounderror-winerror-2-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified/35443495#35443495) that "filename" is used to mean the full/absolute path name. The below will also work.

```py
os.rename((directory + name), (directory + '0' + name))
```