# Have an error FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test.txt'

Tags: python-3.x

Consider:

```
    f = open("test.txt")
            ^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test.txt'
```

I have that text document, but it still happens to be an error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FileNotFoundError: \[WinError 2\] The system cannot find the file specified:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35443278/filenotfounderror-winerror-2-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified)

Comment: Is the `^` actually placed under the `(`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet you do *not* have this file. At least not in the same directory from where you run your python script. If you put `test.txt` into `/tmp/` and you execute python from `/home/user/`, you will get this exception even when your script is in `/tmp/` as well.

So in this case, `cd` to `/tmp/` and run your program from there.

Comment: This is correct. let's say you need to write some unit tests for s3. You can create a dummy file, but where should you put it? Obviously in your tests folder and not in root. but if you refer to the file in your tests such as "dummy_file.txt" you will get an file not found, why because your running from your root and not from within your tests. "tests/dummy_file.txt" does the trick

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using`\` slash. Change them to `/` like below:

```
f = open("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Documents/test.txt")
print(f.read())
```

and you will be okay.

Comment: What slash do you see?

Answer (score 0):

If you use ***Visual Studio Code***
You should note that you have opened the working environment ***exactly*** from inside the folder where the Python file is located

Comment: This is the exact same answer as to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65264607/).