# "for filename in os.listdir" results in error "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Tags: python, file, operating-system

I try to list a file from a directory in not the working directory:

```
import os

for filename in os.listdir("home/pc/folder/logs/user1/):
    path = "home/pc/folder/logs/')
    name_of_file = filename[0]
    filepath_users_next = os.path.join(path, name_of_file)

print(name_of_file)
```

`os.listdir` returns:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

The directory is the same and it’s not empty.

Comment: You probably meant `"/home/..."` - mind the first slash...

Comment: Yes right first time using os.listdir confused Thank you

Comment: What is the canonical Stack Overflow question covering the sole answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate (suggested by a posting of an exact same answer): *[Have an error FileNotFoundError: \[Errno 2\] No such file or directory: 'test.txt'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42473481/)* (2017).

Comment: Which points to *[FileNotFoundError: \[WinError 2\] The system cannot find the file specified:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35443278/filenotfounderror-winerror-2-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified)* (2016).

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code):

You should note that you have open the working environment *exactly* from inside the folder where the Python file is located.

Comment: This would suggest some kind of canonical Stack Overflow question covers it. What is it?