# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'statistics.csv'

Tags: path, operating-system, filenotfounderror

```
txt = open("statistics.csv")
```

Keep getting this error, FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'statistics.csv', however the file is in the same folder as main.py

```
Projects:
  US_statistics:
    statistics.csv
    main.py
```

tried using path

```
C:\Users\user_name\OneDrive\Documents\CODE\Programs\Python\Projects\US_statistics\statistics.csv
```

yet I still get the same error.

used os.getcwd and os.path.realpath(**file**) and paths match up to where the files are.

Comment: [Some](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35443278/) [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42473481/) [candidates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65264607/for-filename-in-os-listdir-results-in-error-filenotfounderror-errno-2-no-s?noredirect=1&lq=1). 2016, 2016, and 2020, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run it directly over

```
python main.py
```

instead of in a environment or over the run button from Visual Studio Code
this should work?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you use ***Visual Studio Code***
You should note that you have opened the working environment ***exactly*** from inside the folder where the Python file is located

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The exact same answer was posted [to two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73290412) [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73290583).