# Python Selenium TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

My webscraper doesn't work. It's giving me this error, "TypeError: **init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given."

I get that error when I tried opening with Edge, Chrome, and Firefox.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path="C:\\Users\.......\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\selenium\edgedriver_win64\msedgedriver.exe")
driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
driver.get("https://www.udemy.com/topic/python/")
driver.quit()
```

I looked at example code from other people and it looked the same as what I did.

Also, the program is in the D drive while the edgedriver_win64 is in the C drive. I don't know if that makes a difference though.

Here is the full stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programs and STEM\Python\Self-Taught Programmer\udemy_course_scraper.py", line 57, in <module>
    scrape.scrape_website()
  File "D:\Programs and STEM\Python\Self-Taught Programmer\udemy_course_scraper.py", line 22, in scrape_website
    driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path="C:\\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\selenium\edgedriver_win64\msedgedriver.exe")
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\edge\webdriver.py", line 66, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=capabilities)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 319, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 374, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 402, in _request
    resp = http.request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\request.py", line 72, in request
    **urlopen_kw)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\request.py", line 150, in request_encode_body
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 315, in urlopen
    conn = self.connection_from_host(u.host, port=u.port, scheme=u.scheme)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 231, in connection_from_host
    return self.connection_from_context(request_context)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 244, in connection_from_context
    return self.connection_from_pool_key(pool_key, request_context=request_context)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 265, in connection_from_pool_key
    pool = self._new_pool(scheme, host, port, request_context=request_context)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 199, in _new_pool
    return pool_cls(host, port, **request_context)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 179, in __init__
    self.pool = self.QueueCls(maxsize)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: can you add full stack trace here

Comment: You didn't escape all the '\'s in your path. Is that accurate to what you are actually running?

Comment: Okay. I got another error after I put the msedgedriver.exe file in this location, C:\Users\.......\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts

I am now getting this error:
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: I updated with the full stack trace I got from executing the code above.

Answer (score 0):

I had several issues with the webdriver module finding my exact location of the driver even if it was in the same folder. This was because if you are running this as a script I believe python by itself checks Its own scripts folder first for any kind of driver executable.

I was able to solve this issue by placing the msedgedriver.exe, chromedriver.exe, etc in my 
python scripts folder. I hope this helps. Then I was able to run     `driver = webdriver.Edge()`

```
C:\Program Files\Python37\Scripts
```

Comment: the location can be anywhere on your PATH, or it can be explicitly set in your code

Comment: Okay. I put the driver under the Scripts folder and I am now getting this error: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: There is something in your script that is not setting the correct path to something. see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35443278/filenotfounderror-winerror-2-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified

Comment: I tried both the PATH method and explicitly set in my code. Neither work. 

It seems the new PATH variable wasn't recognized even after I restarted the command prompt. I also tried restarting the entire computer and that didn't work too.